# Remove nodes from graph not present in second graph networkx

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, networkx

I'm working with networkx and I have two graphs; G1 and G2. To use networkx.difference the nodes in the graphs must be the same, so I need to remove the nodes in G1 not present in G2 and vice versa.

The thought process I had for going about this was to get a listing of nodes from each, and then using "not in" for each entry. This seems really slow and these are very large graphs. Is there a better way of going about this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your task, you need to identify the nodes that are in common to G1 and G2.  Depending on the type of G1 and G2, Python sets may be the easiest way to do that.  Here is a simplified example that can be scaled up to your case assuming G1 and G2 can be cast/copied into sets.

```
g1 = list("ABCDEF")
g2 = list("DEFGHI")

g1_g2_intersection = set(g1) & set(g2)
print(g1_g2_intersection)
```

```
{'D', 'F', 'E'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

First, identify the nodes to remove, which is the union of the nodes in G1 not in G2 and vice_versa:

```
print("nodes in G1 not present in G2:", G1.nodes() - G2.nodes()) 
print("nodes in G2 not present in G1:", G2.nodes() - G1.nodes()) 

nodes_to_remove = (G1.nodes() - G2.nodes()) | (G2.nodes() - G1.nodes())   # '|' -> union between sets:
```

Then you can remove all these nodes using:

```
G1.remove_nodes_from(nodes_to_remove)
G2.remove_nodes_from(nodes_to_remove)
```

---

Here is a small example:

```py
G1 = nx.barabasi_albert_graph(20, 2, seed=2)
G2 = nx.barabasi_albert_graph(10, 2, seed=2)

print("nodes in G1 not present in G2:", G1.nodes() - G2.nodes()) 
print("nodes in G2 not present in G1:", G2.nodes() - G1.nodes()) 

nodes_to_remove = (G1.nodes() - G2.nodes()) | (G2.nodes() - G1.nodes())

print(nodes_to_remove)
G1.remove_nodes_from(nodes_to_remove)
G2.remove_nodes_from(nodes_to_remove)

print(G1.nodes() == G2.nodes())
```